# jquery filter out specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing accordion-style behavior, where only one element can be displayed at one point. I thought it'd be simplistic to implement a `show(e)` function that takes an element, `e`, to be displayed and hides everything BUT `e`. It saves me the hassle of keeping track of which element is being displayed as well. I could just attach `show(e)` as a callback to each element of the accordion.

To do so, I was thinking the only way is to use `.each()` to iterate through all the elements ad compare each one to `e`, hiding it if it isn't equal to `e`.

However, I recall there being a jQuery `.filter` function (http://api.jquery.com/filter/) but it only matches with the element, and not the opposite. (i.e. if I call the function and pass it `e` it'll only match `e` and not everything BUT `e`.)

Is there any way to do so, or are there any recommendations for creating an accordion in general? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well then you should consider using `.not()` function.

```
var excludeTheseDOMElements = $('#something');
$('match_something').not(excludeTheseDOMElements).each(function(){
     //do stuff here
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also use the `:not()` pseudo selector -

```
$('match_something:not(#something)').each(function(){
    //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: ...this is awesome. thanks so much. ("You can accept an answer in 3 minutes")